# Build history out of date

Tags: travis-ci

Our build history hasn't updated in 4 days even there there are several builds per day (https://travis-ci.org/mitodl/lore/builds).  It starting to become a problem for our release processes.  Does anyone know how we can get it fixed?

Comment: You may have to take that up with Travis CI support.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured it out.  As for contacting their support, all I saw was a link to SO or an IRC channel as best I can tell for travis-ci.org

Answer (score 1):

It turns out we had disabled push based builds in our settings, and re-enabling those started adding builds to the build-history tab.